# When should I var_export(..., TRUE), when FALSE?

Tags: php, numbers, export, number-formatting

I have an array that I want to write to a file. This file will be included in another script and the array read and processed.

The array contains floating point numbers rounded to two decimals using `number_format(round($number, 2), 2, '.', '')` (to preserve zeros):

```
print_r($array,true);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 320
            [1] => 128
            [2] => 4.10
            [3] => 4.10
        )

    [1] => Array

etc.
```

When I `var_export` the array, setting `$return = FALSE`, it is exported with the fixed-point numbers enclosed in quotation marks:

```
$data = '<?php $array =' . var_export($array, FALSE) . '; ?>';
file_put_contents ($filename, $data);

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 320,
    1 => 128,
    2 => '4.10',
    3 => '4.10',
  ),
  1 =>

etc.
```

When I `var_export` with `$return = TRUE`, there are no quotation marks:

```
$data = '<?php $array =' . var_export($array, TRUE) . '; ?>';
file_put_contents ($filename, $data);

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 320,
    1 => 128,
    2 => 4.10,
    3 => 4.10,
  ),
  1 =>

etc.
```

From tests, I know that both codes will execute the same on my system. So what am I missing? When should I use `TRUE` and when `FALSE`, and what is the purpose of those quotation marks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter defines whether `var_export` will return its representation of the value, or `echo` it directly.

Look at this example:

```
$x = array(1);
$r_false = var_export($x, false);  // array ( 0 => 1, )
$r_true = var_export($x, true);    // **nothing is printed**
var_export($r_false);              // NULL
var_export($r_true);               // 'array ( 0 => 1, )'
```

Both of the examples you provide should work, but I would be very surprised if they produce the same file.

Here is what I would expect from each:

```
$array = array(1);
$data = '<?php $array =' . var_export($array, TRUE) . '; ?>';
file_put_contents($filename, $data);

// contents of file:
<?php $array =array ( 0 => 1, ); ?>

//
// VS:
//

$array = array(1);
$data = '<?php $array =' . var_export($array, TRUE) . '; ?>';
file_put_contents($filename, $data);

// contents of file:
<?php $array =; ?>

// Here the value of $data is NULL, which becomes ''
```

Comment: Your explanation of what will be the contents of the file are most helpful. Thank you for that great answer :-)